# Is there an official Hex Color Code for the Esperanto green and what is it?

Tags: culture

Is there any official or widely accepted Hex Color Code for the color symbolizing Esperanto?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Esperanto Wikipedia article about the flag](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto-flago) happens to have a section about this.

There is no official color, and various organizations and people have used various shades of green for the flag and other Esperanto symbols, including **#009900** (in the website Flags of the World as well as the SVG file found [in Wikimedia Commons](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosiero:Flag_of_Esperanto.svg)), **#007D13** (TEJO), **#37A93A** (Google), **#2C693F**, etc. The flag itself doesn't seem to have been made official by UEA.

There was even [a debate](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskuto:Esperanto-flago#Koloro) in the Esperanto Wikipedia about this, where it is made clear that no official color exist. So, basically, you can use any shade of dark green you want.